# Confirm Auto Sending an Outlook Email Notification when specific cell on Excel Worksheet Is Updated

Tags: excel, vba

I have code to auto send email (with send confirmation) on a worksheet change. The confirmation appears on every change.

How can I make the confirmation be based on a certain word like "Done" in any cell?
Or maybe when I press save CTRL+S will trigger it, and also would be perfect if the code can mention the new changes in the email body like "Audio mixing - Eps 10 is done".

It is a daily work sheet for audio post production progress, it has 10 columns like "Music" "Dialogue Mix" "Audio mixing" etc. and 30 rows (Episodes) in total.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim nConfirmation As Integer
    Dim objNewWorkbook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim objNewWorksheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim objOutlookApp As Object
    Dim objMail As Object  

    nConfirmation = MsgBox("Send an email notification about the sheet updating now?", vbInformation + vbYesNo, "Mail Sheet Updates")

    If nConfirmation = vbYes Then
        ActiveWorkbook.Save
        Call EmailHyperlink
    End If
End Sub


Sub EmailHyperlink()
    Dim xOtl As Object
    Dim xOtlMail As Object
    Dim xStrBody As String
    Dim NameOfWorkbook
    
    xStrBody = "Hi," & "<br>" & "I want to inform you that:<br><B>" & _
              ActiveWorkbook.Name & "</B> has been updated." & "<br>" _
              & "Please find the file in the Dropbox folder or click " & "<a href=""link"">Here</a> to open file location." & "<br>" _
              & "<br>" & "Regards," & "<br>" & "<br>" & "Alex"
                                      
    On Error Resume Next
    Set xOtl = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set xOtlMail = xOtl.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    With xOtlMail
        .to = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = ""
        .Htmlbody = .Htmlbody & xStrBody
        .send                  
    End With
    
    Set xOtl = Nothing
    Set xOtlMail = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: About the sending moment, you can use `Workbook_BeforeSave` event. "Audio mixing - Eps 10 is done" would be a string which to be added each time, or should it  be collected from the worksheet? You already have `xStrBody` defined. Where would you like putting "Audio mixing - Eps 10 is done"?

Comment: `Target` is a reference to the cell(s) that have changed and you can check if the value is "Done"

Comment: @FaneDuru running before saving could have the same issue if auto-save is on

Comment: @ Super Symmetry: Then, Auto - Save must be set to Off... He said that it would be good to send the mail when he saves. What else do you think would be more appropriate?

Comment: @FaneDuru you're right, sorry I missed that part

Comment: @FaneDuru Thank you for the answer, I tried Workbook_BeforeSave but it didn't work for some reason, maybe I made a mistake, could you please update my code? About the message, it should be collected every time depending on the job done.

Comment: @Super Symmetry Thank you for replay, sorry I didn't understand what do. About auto save, you are absolutely right! I already turned it off when I was trying.  Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "it didn't work for some reason"? Did your previous/initial code work? If yes, you should copy everything from `Worksheet_Change` event, in the new used one. Do you receive an error? Didn't the code do anything? Do you have Events Enabled? Try putting a code line in the event `MsgBox "It works..."`. Is it showing up? Did you put the code in the `Workbook_BeforeSave` event from `ThisWorkbook`, I suppose. Where the `Sub EmailHyperlink()` is? It should be in a standard module! Or put it in `Thisworkbook`, but not so elegant...

Comment: @FaneDuru  I will try that. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the alternative answer which uses Workbook_BeforeClose.

1. Insert a new **module** in the workbook and add the following code. This introduces a global variable Store and also contains the EmailHyperlink procedure.

```
Public Store As String

Public Sub EmailHyperlink(List As String)
    Dim Body As String

    Body = "Hi,<br><br>I want to inform you that:<br><b>" _
           & ActiveWorkbook.Name & "</b> has been updated.<br>" _
           & List & "<br>" _
           & "Please find the file in the Dropbox folder or click " _
           & "<a href=""link"">Here</a> to open file location.<br><br>" _
           & "Regards,<br><br>Alex"

    On Error Resume Next
    With CreateObject("Outlook.Application").CreateItem(olMailItem)
        .To = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = ""
        .Htmlbody = Body
        .Send
    End With
End Sub
```

2. Add the following code in the **sheet**. When you edit a cell in the sheet, if the value of the cell is "Done", a reference is saved in the global variable Store.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim Done As String
    
    If UCase(Target(1, 1)) = "DONE" Then
        Done = Cells(1, Target.Column) & " - " & Cells(Target.Row, 1)
        If InStr(Store, Done) = 0 Then
            If Store = "" Then
                Store = Done
            Else
                Store = Store & "<br>" & Done
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

3. Add the following code in the **workbook**. When you close the worbook, you'll get the email prompt, and the email will now include all the references which were saved in the global variable Store.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim Done() As String
    Dim List As String
    Dim i As Integer
    
    If Store <> "" Then
        Done = Split(Store, "<br>")
        For i = LBound(Done) To UBound(Done)
            List = List & Done(i) & " is done<br>"
        Next
        
        If MsgBox("Send an email notification about the sheet updating now?", _
        vbInformation + vbYesNo, "Mail Sheet Updates") = vbYes Then
            ActiveWorkbook.Save
            Call EmailHyperlink(List)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Dude, useful isn't enough word for this, same as my thanks! :) You really made my evening! Thanks ♥ - Hug♥ - Kiss♥

Comment: You're very welcome. I'm glad you're happy with it :)

Answer (score 0):

I've updated your code a little. See if this is what you are after. When a cell is edited, this will check to see if the last word is "done" (case doesn't matter) and if so it will then prompt to send email. It will also pass through the column name and row so that the email body can mention the change, e.g. "Audio mixing - Eps 10 is done".

**Update:** This now passes through the value from the same row in column A instead of the row number.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If UCase(Right(Target, 4)) = "DONE" Then
        If MsgBox("Send an email notification about the sheet updating now?", _
        vbInformation + vbYesNo, "Mail Sheet Updates") = vbYes Then
            ActiveWorkbook.Save
            Call EmailHyperlink(Cells(1, Target.Column), Cells(Target.Row, 1))
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Sub EmailHyperlink(ColumnName As String, Episode As String)
    Dim xOtl As Object
    Dim xOtlMail As Object
    Dim xStrBody As String

    xStrBody = "Hi," & "<br>" & "I want to inform you that:<br><B>" & _
               ActiveWorkbook.Name & "</B> has been updated." & "<br>" _
               & ColumnName & " - " & Episode & " is done." & "<br>" _
               & "Please find the file in the Dropbox folder or click " _
               & "<a href=""link"">Here</a> to open file location." & "<br>" _
               & "<br>" & "Regards," & "<br>" & "<br>" & "Alex"

    On Error Resume Next
    Set xOtl = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set xOtlMail = xOtl.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    With xOtlMail
        .to = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = ""
        .Htmlbody = .Htmlbody & xStrBody
        .Send
    End With
    Set xOtl = Nothing
    Set xOtlMail = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the code - It works just fine however, i changes the code to Workbook_BeforeClose as i found this more useful! all fine now but i got one issue only.             

I am using first 3 rows as headers so the ColumnName in email body is fine but the row name is wrong (always +3) I tried =Row() - 3 and hide rows and columns headers, it looks fine but it didn't fix the naming issue, is it possible to swap & Row & with Cell value? so the code will copy the cell value in the same row in column A into email body?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Screenshot:(https://www.dropbox.com/s/iucldb34xh7w8c3/Screenshot%202020-08-16%2021.38.44.jpg?dl=0)

Comment: No problem. I've updated it now so it passes through the value from the same row in column A instead of the row number. Is this what you were after?

Comment: Thanks for the update buddy, it works as expected. One last thing if you don't mind, how can i update the code to Workbook_BeforeClose instead of Worksheet_Change? I found this more useful.

Comment: Would you like it so that when you close the workbook, you'll get a prompt asking if you want to send the email and the email will contain a list of all the updates?

Comment: Exactly, its more useful than "Done" method because sometimes i only update dates or when i start a new progress "Working on it" so its better to do everything at close, i also use protect sheet at close but i couldn't mix that with your code, i tried a lot of things with no success! I still a noob in coding :(    Thanks ♥

Comment: I've now added a seperate answer which uses Workbook_BeforeClose. Hopefully it's useful :)